# How to delete all github repository?

Tags: github

I want to reset github repos.want to clean it.
But github repo can not delete from CLI.It can delete by webUI.

How to delete all github repository?more easy.more smart.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to what you ask is probably [`hub`](https://hub.github.com/) which is a CLI interface to Github and lets you fork repositories, create issues and pull-requests, all directly from your terminal.

However, [it doesn't currently support](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/494) *deleting* a repository.